# Font color change in textfield

Tags: html, css

I have made some css styling for the textbox.

```
<div style="margin:10px">
<input type="text" value="Username" class="textbox3" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'">
</div>​​​​​​
```

and the CSS

```
.textbox3{
    color:#202020;
    padding:0 5px 0 10px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    height:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    margin:0;
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius:3px;
    width: 150px;
}
.textbox3:focus{
    color:#202020;
    border:1px solid #4e8abf;
}
.textbox3:focus, .textbox3{
 -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}​
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AWmUg/

But the default color of the text is dark grey. I wanted to change the color of this default text "Username" to a much lighter color say #cdcdcd and when we type any other text, it should be the dark grey. How can I get this result?

Comment: Have you considered using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead? See http://jsfiddle.net/3PLRA/

Comment: You should try the placeholder attribute http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that. can you advice me?

Comment: @XaviLópez beat me to it

Comment: And if you want to change the color of that placeholder you could use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML5 new `placeholder` attribute instead, and use proprietary styles to have different color for placeholders and different color on and off focus

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9QW3w/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Demo" />
```

CSS

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff0000;
}

input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ff0000;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: `:-ms-input-placeholder` for internet explorer

Comment: oh yea, IE10...thanks for the reminder..finally IE getting in the game

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a similar effect using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
```

See it in action in this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/3PLRA

There are lots of resources out there on this attribute, including how to provide [JS fallback](http://www.morethannothing.co.uk/2010/01/placeholder-text-in-html5-a-js-fallback/) mehcanisms if the browser doesn't support HTML5.

In order to style the `placeholder` attribute, for example, take a look at [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2610497/851811).

```
.textbox3::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:    #F00;
}
.textbox3:-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #F00;
}
.textbox3:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color:    #F00;
}
```

See an example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqcqE/)

Comment: what about the different placeholder color?

Comment: @RandomGuy added link to related SO question and example.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML5 you can use the `placeholder` attribute

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp for more info.

Browser that support HTML5 will do this for you.

Comment: the link you've given , does not work. Please update it.